# How to work with a big linked excel source file to access DB?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 220k rows in excel with approx 20 columns.
I linked the excel file to ms access, and I want to create a form in access that display the result of a query. The query itself is based on the excel file.

When I try to create the form, it's impossibly slow because I guess it opens the source excel file through access?. What can I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel really bogs down with that much data. I suggest you move to a proper database.

Comment: the thing is, when i open the file on excel, it doesnt bug at all. I didnt put the data in a table. It's very quick, even when filtering.  But why does it bog when I open it through access?...

Comment: Consider scrapping excel and move the data to a table in access?

Comment: the problem is im using excel to automate several things. The excel file is itself an "app". I know it's not ideal..

Comment: If excel does not bog down, why not build the form in it and use ADODB to run your queries directly in excel? Also, can you please clarify what do you mean by *trying to create the form*? It the form built at runtime?

Comment: Excel doesn't bog down because it's opening and reading the file directly. What you're doing requires that ADO open the file and feed it to Access, which is considerable work. It's ridiculous trying to use Excel as a database - it isn't one. It's a spreadsheet. If you choose to use it in a way it's not designed or intended to be used, you have to live with the consequences of doing so.